# FFT freqency bin center in R

Tags: fourier-transform, r

I'm trying to do a spectral analysis in R. I learned it in Python from Allen Downey's ThinkDSP book.

What is the R equivalent of the Python numpy function, numpy.fft.fftfreq?

If you provide a window length and spacing, that function returns the frequency bin centers. I've been hunting through R package documentation and StackOverflow. Is there an equivalent function in R?

Comment: I don't know the answer but you should check the "signal" package on cran.

Comment: @markleeds That's something to go on, and there is a lot to explore in that package. Thanks for the tip.